# Lazy loading Children not loading

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

I have a question about lazy module.
I have multiple lazy modules working at the moment, except for the last one.
I created a lazy module with two children, but for some reason the page is not loading.

I tried a lot of things already.
Added the a path name, added the pathMatch: 'full' but nothing seems to be working.

AppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  //{ path: 'lottery-games', component: LotteryGamesComponent },
  //{ path: 'lottery-games/detail', component: LotteryGamesDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'lottery-games',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./components/lottery-games/lottery-games.module').then((m) => m.LotteryGamesModule),
  },
```

second routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LotteryGamesComponent },
  { path: 'detail', component: LotteryGamesDetailComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LotteryGamesRoutingModule {}
```

Second module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LotteryGamesComponent, LotteryGamesDetailComponent, LotteryGamesListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LotteryGamesRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
})
export class LotteryGamesModule {}
```

Folder structure:

- lottery-games

  - lottery-games-detail

    - lottery-games-detail.component.ts
  - lottery-games-list

    - lottery-games-list.component.ts
- lottery-games.module.ts
- lottery-games-routing.module.ts
- lottery-games.component.ts

Lottery-games.component

```
<mat-card>
  <h2 class="title">Overzicht</h2>
  <hr />

  <mat-card-content>
    <ng-container *ngIf="lotteryGames$ | async as lotteryGamesList">
      <ng-container *ngIf="lotteryGamesList.length > 0">
        <app-lottery-games-list [LotteryGamesList]="lotteryGamesList"></app-lottery-games-list>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf="lotteryGamesList.length === 0 || lotteryGamesList === null">
        <div class="no-results">
          <p class="no-result-p">Geen resultaten gevonden</p>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image]

I need an extra pair of eyes.
I can't seem to find it

I didn't have any errors, so it looks like it can't find my routes.
But when I go to the details page directly in the address bar it works.
Only the parent component is not working

Comment: If the application match the route but you don't see your lottery-games component may can to be a CSS problem? Can you see the component in the DOM?

Comment: @NiccolòBiagi, no he is not loading at all, I tried a console.log in the OnInit, but it is not showing the log. normally with the CSS is nothing wrong. I used it in all my other components. it is just styling of a div and styling of the mat-card. nothing else.
Before I added lazy loading my component was working, so in that case, I know my component works. I think there is something wrong with de lazy loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In my Module I did the import for my component, but the path was '..' that was not working, and it took a long time to find this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 15, use: `redirectTo: ''`.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: '',
        component: HomeComponent, 
        pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
]
```

This works for me!